# ExpressJS with PassportJS: Session handling

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I am using passportJS for authentication. My configuration is as below:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'/tmp'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use( express.cookieParser() );
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now from the login page to the next page I can access the `req.user.username` variable.

However let's say I define a new variable for the session, ie `req.session.x` , it doesn't persist across the web application.

Now, to make things worse, it's working in my development machine but not in the deployment environment. I've compared the nodejs, local and global plugins version, they are identical.

Anything else I should check? Thanks.

My passport code as below;

```
//Login 
app.get('/login',login.login);
app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/loginSuccess',
    failureRedirect : '/loginFailure'
    }
));

app.get('/loginSuccess',login.success);
app.get('/loginFailure',login.fail);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose/');
mongoose.connect('mongodb:<>');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserDetail = new Schema({
    username : String,
    password : String
}, {
    collection : 'user'
});
var UserDetails = mongoose.model('user', UserDetail);

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) 
{
    process.nextTick(function() {    
        UserDetails.findOne({
            'username' : username,},
        function(err,user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null,false);
            }
            if (user.password != password) {
                return done(null,false);
            }
            return done(null, user);
         });
     });
}));
```

Comment: What is your passport configuration?  My guess is the difference is with the NODE_ENV variable.  You can try changing it to production on dev box and see if it is still working

Comment: My passport script updated above...no luck on changing NODE_ENV to production on dev box, it is still working